# Creating a database in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-2008, visual-basic

I'm studying computing and I need to make a program for my project. My project is a fast food ordering system which needs a database. While trying to add a SQL Service Database I get an error message telling me to download SQL 2005/8. I cannot do this as I have recently upgraded to Windows 10. It would be of great help if anyone could tell me any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically need the 2005 or 2008 versions (which I doubt if it's a student project) then I'd suggest obtaining the latest available version of SQL Server Express Edition from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx). It will install fine on Windows 10.